# Add class if form field is invalid

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using jQuery validation for ajax form submission and I would like to add a class to the errorContainer if any of the text inputs have a class 'error'. Seems simple but I think it's a scope issue?

```
if ($('#myInput').hasClass('error')) { 
  $('#errorContainer').addClass('foo'); 
}
```

I have placed this outside the submit handler, inside submit handler, outside of validation call, inside validation call... all to no avail. Has anyone done this simple task with success?

Comment: $('input[type=text]')  is a generic selector..   You seem to be checking for all the textboxes at once.. If you have more than one it will check for the first textbox in the page.. Try to be more specific

Comment: I can't seem to figure out the issue, so what I did was add a class 'error' to the error container. then remove it on success function in submit handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if ($('input[type=text].error').length > 0) { 
  $('#errorContainer').addClass('foo'); 
}
```

The selector `$('input[type=text].error')` is going to return an array-like object even if there is only one match. So asking an array if it `hasClass('error')` doesn't make sense.

What you really want to do is put a container around your elements you want to check for the error class. You might already have a container like the form (if it is all the inputs on the form). Then you can do something like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="a" />
  <textarea name="b"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

With JavaScript:

```
$(':input.error', '#myForm').length > 0
```

Here is an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ecCt/). Note that using the [:input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) will more input types than just  `input` which may be what you want.

Comment: Technically calls to the jQuery function that are passed a selector - such as `$('input[type=text].error')` - return an **array-like** jQuery object, not an actual array. The resulting object **does** have a `.hasClass()` function, it just only acts on the *first* element matched.

Comment: Seems simple. Can't get it to work, keep in mind Im using jQuery validate, would you put this inside the scope of the validation call? outside doesn't work

Comment: You could run the validation first. You can do that with a call like `$("#myForm").validate();`.

Comment: nothing seems to work. keep getting 'unexpected toke (' errors

Comment: @AnthonyGrist True. I wanted to keep it simple but I may have over simplified. I've updated the answer slightly.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign You could get it working on jsfiddle first. It takes time however it is a very valuable tool for sharing examples and figuring out bugs.

Comment: Love jsfiddle, there is just a lot of other moving parts that make up the form.

Answer (score 1):

Most functions that return a value (such as `.val()`, `.hasClass()`, etc) will only act on the **first** element in the group of selected elements contained within the jQuery object.

Generally in these cases what you'd need to do is use the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function to iterate over **all** of the elements, and do the test for each of them.

However, since you're testing for a class, you can modify your condition as detailed in Cymen's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and pass in the condition

```
$('#errorContainer').toggleClass('foo',$('input[type=text].error').length > 0);
```

So if there are any with class error.. add class foo.. else remove class foo